# Como passar informação de uma RitchTextBox para documento word

Tags: c#, microsoft-word, richtextbox

*Como faço para passar a informação que está numa RichTextBox para um documento word no C#.*

Código:

```
 String strtxt = rtbVertigo.Text;


            TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Users\edv\Desktop\WORD\Vertigo.doc");

            sw.WriteLine(strtxt);

            sw.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Dados exportados com sucesso");
```

Comment: Não é possível uma conversão direta de RTF para um documento Word. Embora você possa simplesmente salvar o seu arquivo RTF e ele será compatível para leitura no Word.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta.Após mais algumas tentativas consegui fazer a passagem da informação da RTF para um word. Editei a publicação com o código correto

Comment: @IderOdg Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos. E não se esqueça de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/).

Comment: O ideal, é que você mantenha a sua pergunta como estava e publique a solução como resposta ou apague a sua pergunta. E note que em sua solução você não está convertento um richtext em um documento word, apenas lendo o plain text e escrevendo dentro de um arquivo com a extensão .doc